# Rails 4 ActiveModel validation of nested attribute (without ActiveRecord)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activemodel

I am working on a small Rails project that simply allows a user to submit a form and the information from the form is sent via an API call to another service for consumption.

Here is my model:

```
class ServiceRequest
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  extend ActiveModel::Naming

  attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name, :prefix, :contact_email, :phone_number,
                :address, :address2, :city, :state, :zip_code, :country,
                :address_type, :troubleshooting_reference, :line_items

  validates_presence_of :first_name, :last_name, :contact_email, :phone_number,
                        :address, :city, :state, :zip_code, :country, :address_type,
                        :troubleshooting_reference

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    super
    @errors = ActiveModel::Errors.new(self)
    @api_response = nil
  end

  def line_items_attributes=(attributes)
    @line_items ||= []
    attributes.each do |i, params|
      @line_items.push(LineItem.new(params))
    end
  end

  def save
    conn = Faraday.new(url: "#{Figaro.env.arciplex_url}") do |faraday|
      faraday.request :url_encoded
      faraday.response :logger
      faraday.adapter  Faraday.default_adapter
    end

    @api_response = conn.post do |req|
      req.url "/api/v1/service_requests?token=#{Figaro.env.api_token}"
      req.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
      req.body = self.to_json
    end

    validate!
  end

  def validate!
    # If successful creation, do nothing
    unless [200, 201].include?(@api_response.status)
      Rails.logger.debug(@api_response.inspect)
      errors.add(:base, @api_response.body)
    else
      return @api_response.body
    end
  end

end
```

And Here is my `LineItem` model:

```
class LineItem
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  attr_accessor :item_type, :model_number, :serial_number, :additional_information

  validates_presence_of :item_type, :model_number, :serial_number
end
```

I am testing the form out and am trying to get the form to fail if the user submits the form without supplying a `:model_number` but the `ServiceRequest` object thinks that it's `valid?` instead of checking the `LineItem` validations.

Anyway to include these validations when I run `@service_request.valid?` in my controller?